# CSS for DIV's jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, css

How can I adjust jQuery-ui.css for the spacing in between DIV's? I am using jQuery 2.1.0 along with there "smoothness" ui. But for some reason I can not get a good grasp of changing there CSS. As you see in the example below I have provided my text boxes are right on top of each other pretty much I just want a little more spacing or padding in between them.. I tried using a `<br>` and that just ends up to be way too much spacing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/acw7z1ob/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
  <label for="vin">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vehicle Identification Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="vin" id="vin" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" size="30" maxlength="30" required="yes" message="Please enter vehicle identification number.">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
  <select name="month1" id="month1" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose a Month</option>
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select name="month2" id="month2" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select name="month3" id="month3" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">

  <label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
  <input type="text" name="ew" id="ew" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" required="yes" message="Please enter empty weight.">

  <label id="gvwLabel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gross Vehicle Weight:*</label>
  <input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `margin` for your text inputs like:

```css
input[type='text'] {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <label for="vin">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vehicle Identification Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="vin" id="vin" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" size="30" maxlength="30" required="yes" message="Please enter vehicle identification number.">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
  <select name="month1" id="month1" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose a Month</option>
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select name="month2" id="month2" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select name="month3" id="month3" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">

  <label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
  <input type="text" name="ew" id="ew" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" required="yes" message="Please enter empty weight.">

  <label id="gvwLabel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gross Vehicle Weight:*</label>
  <input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()">
```

Or you can add margin in class container `clearfix`:

```css
.clearfix {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <label for="vin">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vehicle Identification Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="vin" id="vin" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" size="30" maxlength="30" required="yes" message="Please enter vehicle identification number.">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
  <select name="month1" id="month1" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose a Month</option>
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select name="month2" id="month2" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select name="month3" id="month3" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">

  <label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
  <input type="text" name="ew" id="ew" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" required="yes" message="Please enter empty weight.">

  <label id="gvwLabel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gross Vehicle Weight:*</label>
  <input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()">
```

Comment: Then you have to specify the container like `#testCont > ... > .clearfix {
  margin: 10px;
}` for example and use !important

Comment: Do you have any live example? Doesn't matter where you place it just to load with the rest stuff(i prefer to place in a css file for example).

Comment: @ZaneZ you can try setting it to `margin: 10px !important;` so it takes priority over other css margins set on that object.

Comment: @ZaneZ you could put that in yours.

Comment: @ZaneZ what I would then suggest doing is using the dev-tools, inspecting the element to see what CSS styles are being applied to the input fields. Also, I may suggest trying `padding` instead of `margin`. You can also try applying it to your `div` instead of the `input`

Comment: @ZaneZ it is because of how CSS properties are given priority. So if you have multiple stylsheets applying to the same element it can cause some undesired effects.